# Can't send and find a query in the Class 'app \ models \' not found

Tags: php, yii2

I encountered such a problem, a certain query "name", which the user entered, is not stored in the database, and even this stupid error with which I can not cope at all takes off .. apparently I'm more stupid than her .. please tell me what is the catch?

Here is the error in full format:

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'app\models\' not found

 1. in /var/www/u0598324/public_html/webstels.com/models/ShopPromoItem.php at line 40

                            return [
            'status' => 'Статус',
        ];
    }

    public static function get($id)
    {
        $item = ShopPromoItem::findOne($id);
        $class = 'app\\models\\' . $item->class;
        return $class::findOne($id);
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return Html::encode($this->title);
    }

    public function getPriceArray()
    {


2. yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError()

$_GET = [
'username' => 'swallowsveta1997',
];

$_POST = [
'_csrf' => '2dWdOMdf_z2HrgmbtpnKKN1f-mQnpLEkeqpEkFg8zj6OoOR-sAa2DrOcQ-GG7otyuxSIXEzn6R0M5jX5Cw2cVw==',
'ShopPromoItemBuyForm' => [
    'name' => 'name',
    'item_id' => '1',
],
];

$_COOKIE = [
'_identity' => 'd669e918ca5f102ab0802a521e1d3fc241689f04dbb51253b7b8ab7b54713c5ca:2:{i:0;s:9:"_identity";i:1;s:50:"[22727,"gkEvlaqhpnAtz8mz4v9Fk96QOpkIrssI",2592000]";}',
'PHPSESSID' => 'abe468adef98b859d2100b97cb6da127',
'_csrf' => '542d3bc58acd73dd28aadc1e388c74c2697098a4c8d8bb4b855417ada2ebe4ffa:2:{i:0;s:5:"_csrf";i:1;s:32:"WuyFwYI342Jz0wAZfKr8kCX9vLqiS1Ri";}',
];

$_SESSION = [
'__flash' => [],
'__id' => 22727,
'__authKey' => 'gkEvlaqhpnAtz8mz4v9Fk96QOpkIrssI',
'__expire' => 1543857954,
'__captcha/site/captcha' => 'lesafiq',
'__captcha/site/captchacount' => 1,
];
```

Here is the model ShopPromoItem.php:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use app\helpers\BalanceHelper;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\UserBalance;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Json;

class ShopPromoItem extends ActiveRecord
{
const STATUS_ENABLED = 'enabled';
const STATUS_DISABLED = 'disabled';
const STATUS_DELETED = 'deleted';

public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%shop_promo_item}}';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [

    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'status' => 'Статус',
    ];
}

public static function get($id)
{
    $item = ShopPromoItem::findOne($id);
    $class = '@app/models/' . $item->class;
    return $class::findOne($id);
}

public function getTitle()
{
    return Html::encode($this->title);
}

public function getPriceArray()
{
    return Json::decode($this->price);
}

public function getPriceString()
{
    $prices = $this->getPriceArray();
    $result = '';
    foreach ($prices as $currency => $price) {
        $result .= '<img src="/images/' . $currency . '.png" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 24px;"> ' . BalanceHelper::convertToDigits($price);
    }
    return $result;
}

public function giveTo(User $user)
{

}
}
```

Here is ShopPromoItemBuyForm.php:

```
<?php
namespace app\models\forms;

use app\helpers\BalanceHelper;
use app\helpers\RefererHelper;
use app\helpers\SettingHelper;
use app\models\ShopPromoItem;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\UserPromo;
use app\models\UserBalance;
use app\models\UserOperation;
use yii\validators\IpValidator;

class ShopPromoItemBuyForm extends UserPromo
{
public $item_id;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['item_id', 'required'],
        ['item_id', 'integer'],
        ['item_id', 'exist',
            'targetClass' => '\app\models\ShopPromoItem',
            'targetAttribute' => 'id',
            'filter' => ['status' => ShopPromoItem::STATUS_ENABLED]
        ],

        ['name', 'multProtect']
    ];
}

public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT => ['name']
    ];
}

public function multProtect()
{
    return;

    // disable for debug mode
    if (YII_DEBUG)
        return;

    // check evercookie
    if (isset($_COOKIE['was_promo']) && $_COOKIE['was_promo'] == "true") {
        $this->addError('name', \Yii::t('app', 'Вы уже заказывали сайт с таким названием на проекте, повторный заказ сайта с таким именем запрещён'));
    }
    $validator = new IpValidator();
    if ($validator->validate(\Yii::$app->request->userPromoIP)) {
        $ip = \Yii::$app->request->userPromoIP;
        $userPromo = UserPromo::find()->where(['id' => $ip])->limit(1)->one();
        if ($userPromo !== null) {
            $this->addError('name', \Yii::t('app', 'Вы уже заказывали сайт с таким названием на проекте, повторный заказ сайта с таким именем запрещён'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->addError('name', \Yii::t('app', 'Вы уже заказывали сайт с таким названием на проекте, повторный заказ сайта с таким именем запрещён'));
    }
}

public function buy(User $user)
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('warning', implode('<br />', $this->getFirstErrors()));
        return false;
    }

    if (\Yii::$app->mutex->acquire('balance_' . $user->id)) {
        \Yii::$app->db->transaction(function() use ($user) {
            $item = ShopPromoItem::get($this->item_id);
            $prices = $item->getPriceArray();

            // check balance
            foreach ($prices as $currency => $price) {
                if (!$user->balance->has($currency, BalanceHelper::convertToDigits($price))) {
                    \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('warning', \Yii::t('app', 'Недостаточно средств на балансе'));
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // decrease balance
            foreach ($prices as $currency => $price) {
                $user->balance->decrease($currency, BalanceHelper::convertToDigits($price));
                $user->operation->create(UserOperation::OPERATION_SHOP_PROMO_BUY, $currency, BalanceHelper::convertToDigits($price), [
                    'ShopPromoItem_id' => $this->item_id
                ]);
            }

            $item->giveTo($user);

            // give reward to referer
            RefererHelper::giveReward($user, UserBalance::CURRENCY_USD, BalanceHelper::convertToDigits($prices['usd']));

            $message = '';
            foreach ($prices as $currency => $price) {
                $message .= \Yii::t('app', '{sum} долларов', ['sum' => BalanceHelper::convertToDigits($price)]);
            }

            \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', \Yii::t('app', 'Вы купили «{title}»', ['title' => \Yii::t('app', $item->getTitle())]) .
                '<br />' . \Yii::t('app', 'Потрачено {price}', ['price' => $message]));

            return true;
        });
    }
}
}
```

UserPromo.php:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class UserPromo extends ActiveRecord
{
const STATUS_ENABLED = 'enabled';
const STATUS_DISABLED = 'disabled';
const STATUS_DELETED = 'deleted';

public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%user_promo}}';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['id', 'exist'],
        ['user_id', 'integer'],

        ['name', 'required'],
        ['name', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['name', 'match', 'pattern' => '#^[\w_-]+$#i'],
        ['name', 'unique', 'targetClass' => self::className(), 'message' => \Yii::t('app', 'Указанное название для вашего сайта уже занято')],
        ['name', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'status' => 'Статус',
        'name' => \Yii::t('app', 'Название'),
    ];
}

public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    $identity = static::findOne(['id' => $id]);
    return $identity;
}

public static function findByName($name)
{
    return static::findOne(['name' => $name]);
}

public function getName()
{
    return Html::encode($this->name);
}

public function getPromo()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Promo::className(), ['id' => 'promo_id']);
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}

public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->promo->getTitle();
}

public function getType()
{
    return $this->promo->getType();
}

public function getProfit($type)
{
    return $this->promo->{$type . '_profit'};
}
}
```

PromoSiteShopItem.php:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use app\helpers\BalanceHelper;
use app\helpers\SettingHelper;

class PromoSiteShopItem extends ShopPromoItem
{
public function giveTo(User $user)
{
    (new UserPromo([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'promo_id' => 21,
        'created_at' => time(),
        'status' => UserPromo::STATUS_ENABLED
    ]))->save(false);

    $prices = $this->getPriceArray();

    // increase reserve
    $value = SettingHelper::get('reserve.promo.sum') + intval(BalanceHelper::convertToDigits($prices['usd']) / 100 * 50);
    SettingHelper::set('reserve.promo.sum', $value);
}
}
```

Promo.php:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class Promo extends ActiveRecord
{
const TYPE_PROMO = 'promo';

const STATUS_ENABLED = 'enabled';
const STATUS_DISABLED = 'disabled';
const STATUS_DELETED = 'deleted';

public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%promo}}';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['user_id', 'integer'],
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'status' => 'Статус',
    ];
}

public function getType()
{
    return $this->type;
}

public function getTitle()
{
    return Html::encode($this->title);
}
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers\user\main\services;

use app\components\Controller;
use app\models\ShopPromoItem;
use app\models\forms\ShopPromoItemBuyForm;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\helpers\Url;

use app\models\UserPromo;

class PromoController extends Controller
{
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (\Yii::$app->params['user']['promo']['temporaryDisabled']) {
        throw new ForbiddenHttpException('Заказ временно приостановлен');
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}

public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->layout = 'page';

    $items = ShopPromoItem::find()->where([
        'status' => ShopPromoItem::STATUS_ENABLED
    ])->all();

    $model = new ShopPromoItemBuyForm();
    if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->buy(\Yii::$app->user->identity);
    }

    $promo = UserPromo::find()->where([
        'user_id' => \Yii::$app->user->identity->id,
        'status' => UserPromo::STATUS_ENABLED
    ])->with('promo')->orderBy('promo_id DESC')->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'items' => $items,
        'model' => $model,
        'promo' => $promo,
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: You can directly use `$item->class` instead of `$class = '@app/models/' . $item->class;` cause you are already in `app\models`

Comment: @Insane Skull Greetings, wrote this: `$item = ShopPromoItem::findOne($id);
        $class = $item->class;
        return $class::findOne($id);`, but now comes the error "Class name must be a valid object or a string"

Comment: what is `$item->class` returns? If you want class name from object use `get_class($item)`;